# How to implement an atomic commit of a multi-party transaction

Tags: corda

What is the best way to partially hide/mask the data between the counterparties of the same transactions? E.g. Alice wants to give Bob $5 and give Charlie $3. It must be a single atomic transaction, but she doesn't want Bob and Charlie to either know **who** the other parties are nor **what** is being committed to.

My understanding is that I would form a transaction with common data as an attachment, then individual parts of transaction as separate outputs for corresponding counterparties, and then...?

From reading documentation, it seems that FilteredTransaction is the way to do it, but I do not see how can I collate the signatures back into the transactions to be submitted for FinalityFlow.

Comment: The issue with using a filtered transaction is that neither party will want to sign it because they don't know what's being hidden. For example, you could filter out states showing that all their cash is being transferred to you. So they cannot sign in the blind. If the tx metadata could somehow provide guarantees (e.g. the filtered-out states don't belong to you), this might work, but it isn't implemented yet.

Comment: @joel Thanks for the answer! I understand the trust issues with this approach, so my question is more on the technical implementation level. Would using AnonymousParty from your answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529134/best-way-to-create-atomic-transactions-using-corda-flows/48540774?noredirect=1#comment84115401_48540774 help?

Comment: AnonymousParty would hide the identity of the participants, but not the contents of the transaction (e.g. the fact two amounts of cash are being transferred).

Comment: So then AnonymousParty for privacy combined with FilteredTransaction for confidentiality?

Comment: But as I mentioned above, I don't think filtered transactions work because how do you know the transaction you're partially signing doesn't also involve transferring away $100,000 from you to the counterparty?

Answer (score 0):

Joel makes a very valid point. Hiding parts of the transaction using filtered transactions would open you up to potentially signing over ownership of a state you didn't intend to.

I've not completely thought this through, but you could look into the implications (and potential benefits) of encrypting the value being transferred within each state with two different keys and separately send these keys to Bob and Charlie.

Your contract code would have to allow for Bob and Charlie to exchange the encrypted value state back into a normal state.